# Open a specific folder when a upload field is clicked?

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

i have this link in a form :

```
<input type="file" class="multi" accept="doc|jpg|png|jpeg|tiff" maxlength="1" name="optionPhoto" id="optionPhoto" />
```

But if i want to upload a image i always want that a specific folder is opened. 
for example : libs/uploads/

Now it depends when last folder is opened..

Any way i  can do this in php or html ?

Comment: i don't think you can set a default path when the file button is clicked, thats outside the scope of control of a browser to the machine

Comment: It doesn't even make any sense; most users of your website won't even HAVE a libs/uploads/ directory.