# Open windows explorer using Web Browser - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, browser

Is there any possible way to directly open the specific location in the windows explorer using Web Browser?

What are the ways on how to open windows explorer using PHP or web programming language?

Comment: and now imagine *any website* being able to arbitrarily run commands on the *client computer*. could be opening a windows explorer, could be a nice little `format c:` - no, it's **not** possible, and it **shouldn't**

Comment: A web page in a browser has very little (none) access to underlying operating system - using PHP, you could do it - you'd need an HTTP server and PHP installed on the computer of course

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25997611/5930557 it is not possible

Comment: What will your app do when it's executed on any other operating system than Windows? There's no Windows Explorer on any linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons you can not  open any file from client side automatically. Microsoft provides some access from browser but only from internet explorer using activeX object you can ask to browse a file but can't select one through programming also PHP is server sided language you have lots of accesses in php to access server sided stuffs like accessing files from FTP server managing database deleting files editing its own config files are possible but only in server side